# Makefile: undefined reference to 'std::...'

Tags: c++, unix, makefile, compiler-errors

I have no experience with Unix, and very limited C++ experience. I recently got assigned a coding project that requires us to deliver C++ source code along with a makefile.

The professor gave a sample makefile and mentioned that we should follow its format exactly. I'm trying to get it to work for a single file "main.cpp", which I can compile and run fine using from the terminal after downloading MinGW and Cygwin. However, trying to run the makefile results in a bunch of "undefined reference to ..." errors.

The makefile is: (all that I changed was the name of the project and object file)

```
VPATH = ./src:

.SUFFIXES : .F90 .f .f90 .c .o

# Compiler types
FC = gfortran
CC = gcc
CXX = gcc

# Optimization level
OPT    = -O2

# Relevant flags
FFLAGS = ${OPT} 
CFLAGS = ${OPT} 
CXXFLAGS = ${OPT} 

# Name of the program
PROG  = main.x

# List of object files
OBJ = main.o

.f90.o: 
    ${FC} -c -o $@ ${FFLAGS} $<

.F90.o: 
    ${FC} -c -o $@ ${FFLAGS} $<

.c.o: 
    ${CC} -c -o $@ ${FFLAGS} $<

.cpp.o:
    ${CXX} -c -o $@ ${FFLAGS} $<

all:${PROG}

$(PROG): ${OBJ}
    $(CXX) ${FFLAGS} $(OBJ) -o ${PROG}
    mv ${PROG} ./bin/

clean:
    /bin/rm -f *.mod *.o *.x *~ ./src/*.o ./src/*~

uninstall: 
    rm -f bin/${PROG} 

renew:
    touch *
```

A snippet of the error list that I'm getting is:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1e): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)'
```

The project itself has nothing to do with computer science - this is just the format that we have to give the deliverables in, so I'm a bit frustrated with how much I've struggled to get it to work.

Greatly appreciate any help you all can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
CXX = gcc
```

to

```
CXX = g++
```

The reason is that the

```
$(PROG): ${OBJ}
    $(CXX) ${FFLAGS} $(OBJ) -o ${PROG}
```

rule is currently using the C compiler for the final link, but C++ objects need a little bit of special treatment. Basically `-lstdc++`, which you could have added, but it's better to just use the C++ compiler for the final link instead, especially since the variable named `CXX` customarily represents the C++ compiler, not the C compiler.

FYI, just stylistically, it would also be preferable to replace `${...}` (shell syntax) with `$(...)` (normal Makefile syntax).

Comment: Wow. Such a simple fix, and now everything works. Thanks so much for your help, and for an explanation that I could actually follow!

Comment: You may also use `${CXXFLAGS}` in place of `FFLAGS` because options for languages may be different, so use CXX for C++ compilation.